# OSM Geocoder + Яндекс.Подсказки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, openstreetmap

есть ли какой-то готовый код или подскажите как скрестить подсказки от Яндекс и OpenStreetMap. Проблема в том, что формат, который отдает Яндекс.Подсказки - не подходит для OSM.

Для OSM используется такой запрос [https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=АДРЕС&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=ru](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=%D0%90%D0%94%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%A1&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=ru)

Comment: А чем вам не нравится ответ подсказок Яндекса? В OSM вам нужно вставлять адрес в параметр q=, а подсказки именно адреса и возвращают. Но если всё равно используется карта Яндекса (подсказки без неё нарушают ПС Яндекса), зачем геокодер OSM использовать? Проще всё через API Яндекс Карт геокодировать.

Comment: @YaCor' гео кодер на бэке. И он работает не только с фронтом, а еще с БД. Оттуда тоже получаем для выдачи на фронт

Comment: Ок. Пусть OSM, если он уже работает. Но не ответили, чем не нравится ответ саджеста Яндекса? В нём возвращается форматированный адрес - что не так?

Comment: @YaCor' пришлите документацию, может все-таки вариант хороший